# JSON MySQL database using Java

Tags: mysql, json, database

I am currently writing a Java program and decided to use JSON MySQL as my database.
What is the correct syntax for me to insert a variable to JSON MySQL Database.

Table:

```
mysql> desc sales;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sale  | json    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Java Code:

```
String name = "Izzat";
String place = "Cheras";

String sql = "INSERT INTO sales(id, sale) VALUES ('9','{\"Name\":"+name+",\"Place\":"+place+"}')";
```

I got an error:

INSERT INTO sales(id, sale) VALUES ('9','{"Nama":Izzat,"Place":"Cheras"}')
Data truncation: Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 8 in value for column 'sales.sale'.

May I know what is the correct syntax for this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate cause of the error seems to be that the data is missing double quotes.  So this should work:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO sales(id, sale) ";
sql += "VALUES (9, '{\"Name\": \"" + name + ", \"Place\": \"" + place + "\"}')";
```

### Demo

However, given that the JSON data is coming from your Java code, you should consider using one of the JSON APIs available to generate the JSON string.  Building a JSON string like this manually, as you have just seen, is error prone.

Comment: I'm new with JSON. Will try to look into your suggestion. Thank you very much.